# Mysql query is returning false results

Tags: mysql

I have a products table with a product_id field that is an auto-ID and an integer.
When I search:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE product_id = '73N716507Y5928128'
```

it actually returns the row whose product_id is 73.  And I may be new to programming but I KNOW that 73 != 73N716507Y5928128.

What can I do to fix this?
The reason BTW for this query is that I am searching multiple tables and multiple fields for a search term and using logic to determine what the user is searching for...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the datatype of `product_id`?

Comment: Quotes myself... "product_id field that is an auto-ID and an integer"

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought integer datatype can only store numerical values..

Comment: Yeah I'd try setting your product_id field to a varchar

Comment: It is and that is all that it stores.  That is my problem.  It is returning something and saying that basically 73 matches '73N716507Y5928128'

Comment: Why in the world would I change my product_id auto-incrementing field to a varchar?

Comment: I see, I get what you mean..

Comment: If you pass a string to an integer field,  mysql will take the integer part at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql, when you compare (=, <, >, <=, >=, <=>) a numeric field and a character field, the character field is converted to a number first, disregarding any trailing non-numeric characters.

Presumably you want the `product_id=` part to stay unchanged to take advantage of an index.  You can add an additional condition to test if the input is in fact a number:

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
WHERE product_id = '73N716507Y5928128'
AND CONCAT(0+'73N716507Y5928128')='73N716507Y5928128';
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do to counter this?

Comment: This seems much simpler  `SELECT * FROM products WHERE binary(product_id) = '73N716507Y5928128'`

Comment: @AllenKing yes, but then it would do a full table scan

Comment: @ysth only matters if there are over a million records.  I don't believe there are millions of products.   If the total number of rows are less than 100K,  it will not even be felt.

Answer (score 0):

Your business logic should ensure that only integers are passed in the `where clause`.   However,  you may also try the following,  it will fix the issue.  But if `products` table has millions of records, this will not be a good idea due to table full scan.  But if there are say 10K or less products in the table,  full scan will not be significant at all.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE binary(product_id) = '73N716507Y5928128'
```